# instant swipe using UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm writing this application which is a flashcard app, I would like to create an user interface that shows a different card aka page when ever the user does a horizontal swipe.
I came up with this idea to use a `UIScrollView`, but the problem is that I want the scroll view to show the next page as soon as a swipe happened, and even if I'm to turn the paging on it should be swiped to at least half of the view size for it to trigger, here are different the two different methods i tried:

First I disable scrolling from `UIScrollView` ( using scrolEnabled ) so it would pass the swipe event up to responder chain then added right swipe gesture recognizer to the corresponding view. The problem with this approach is that often gesture recognizer fails to report the swipe event.

Second thing I tried was to use the delegate method

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    static CGFloat lastScrollOffset;
    static BOOL hasScrolled;

    if (lastScrollOffset > theScrollView.contentOffset.x && !hasScrolled){
        NSLog(@"left Swipe");
        [theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) animated:YES];
        if (theScrollView.contentOffset.x == 320) 
            hasScrolled = NO;
        hasScrolled = YES;
    }
    if (lastScrollOffset < theScrollView.contentOffset.x && !hasScrolled){
        NSLog(@"right Swipe");
        [theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480) animated:YES];
        if (theScrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) 
            hasScrolled = NO;
        hasScrolled = YES;
    }
    lastScrollOffset = theScrollView.contentOffset.x;
}
```

doesn't work properly.

I noticed `scrollRectToVisble` gets canceled when there is another touch happening. How accurate is my assumption?

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're disabling scrolling then you probably don't want to use a UIScrollView :)

I would just animate on the next card inside a normal UIView (using [UIView's animation methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3a)) when a swipe is detected.

Comment: thanks mate:) im using `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` and it works perfectly, will vote your answer up when ever I was able to. cheers again

Comment: No problem - I realised after I posted this that another advantage of this method would be not having to create all the cards at one go, only create them when you need to - should help keep the app fast and memory usage low :)

Comment: guess have to post this into a new question but im loading my view from nib, next card is almost the same as first card but with a different question, the problem with `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` is it moves the view then i have to create a view similar to other view so it will take its place by the time original view is moving. there should be a better approach to this right?

Comment: No, that sounds about right - just might make a QuestionView class that extends View so it's easy for you to make a view per question but however you do it, that's the right approach.

Comment: what i came up with was to make snapshot of the current view, then move the view a view-width then animate the photo to a side of screen and animate the original view from the other side to centre. but here is a newbish question ( moving up on your idea ) if i move the original view to other side of screen then how am i going to easily access the view objects on the new view? one way would be to reassign the ivars to new view objects by loop testing them

Comment: I think that we would have written the rest of the app differently; it would never have occured to me to take a snapshot, I would have created a whole new UIView object! I would have a member called currentView that points to the new view. However, your snapshot method would work just as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything called `UISwipeView`, but that's just a side note.

If you have a fixed number of cards you could easily use a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled.

**EDIT:** Even if you have too many cards for such a solution to be feasible you could still use a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled. However it would require some more work.

**EDIT 2:** I just realized that I didn't read your question properly before answering. I don't understand why you wouldn't want to use paging though. I think paging provides better feedback to the user than just instantly switching cards.

Comment: hehe thanks for pointing out the typo :P and i truly don't even know how it will feel like with an instant swipe so, if i manage to figure out how to implement it, i would be able to compare them more easily.